# How to compare two typed objects (with interface) in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

There is a need to get the delta (key/val) of the changed attributes between two object.
The code is typescript.
The two objects were created by same interface.

```
export interface ITestObj {
   att1: string;
   att2: string[];
   att3: string;
}
```

I'm getting error that object's attribute can't be used as index.
Can't do something like this:

```
if(objA['att1'] !== objB['att1']) {
}
```

Trying to fix this, I tried to modify the interface to:

```
export interface ITestObj {
       [att1: string]: string;
       att2: string[];
       att3: string;
    }
```

but this is can't be done as not all attributes are string (or number for this matter...).

How can I get the attributes that are different between objA and objB?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you share a bit more code to help us execute the code and fix the problem?

Comment: I haven't  any error. I ignore the third snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `typeof()` for value type comparisons:

```
if (typeof objA.att1 !== typeof objB.att1) {
    // ...
}
```

See [typeof type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#typeof-type-guards) in the TypeScript documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
if(objA.att1 !== objB.att1) {
}
```

**But** Better is to use

```
if(JSON.stringify(objA) !== JSON.stringify(objB)) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried giving a breakdown of several solutions in the following code:

```
type A = {
  att1: string;
  att2: string[];
  att3: string[];
};

const compare = <T extends {}>(a: T, b: T): boolean => {
  // Now there is several ways of doing this, all come with pros and cons

  // 1. If you are absolutely certain that the objects have ALL the attributes
  // from interface T (and no other attributes hidden from TypeScript)
  // you can just well use something like isEqual from lodash or similar
  // OR take the keys of one of your objects which will give you an array:
  //
  // const keys = ['att1', 'att2', 'att3']
  //
  // And you need to tell TypeScript that you are sure that these keys are exactly the ones from interface T
  // by casting the string[] (that you get from Object.keys) to K[]
  type K = keyof T;
  const keys = Object.keys(a) as K[];

  // Then finally loop over those keys and do the comparison that you want, I just sketched a thing here
  //
  // Note that to compare the string arrays you will need something more sophisticated than '==='!
  for (const key of keys) {
    if (a[key] !== b[key]) return false;
  }

  // 2. If you are not sure about what attributes there might be but the interfaces you need to compare
  // are always the same (i.e. you don't need compare() to be generic)
  //
  // In this case you can either store the keys you expect in a hard-coded array:
  type KA = keyof A;
  const hardcodedKeys: KA[] = ['att1', 'att2', 'att3'];

  // And again do your comparison here

  // You can also go fancy and use something like ts-transformer-keys:
  // https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-transformer-keys
  // which will give you the list of keys for a small price of hooking up the TypeScript transform

  // And again do your comparison here

  return true;
};
```

**But even with the transform you will not be able to make your function generic!** The transform does not know what the type parameter `T` will be because it depends on where the function is called so you cannot extract its keys!

It has to do with TypeScript itself, you have to give it a hand there:

```
// You will need to pass the array of keys to the function explicitly
// and let TypeScript just check that what you passed actually are keys of T
const compareProperties = <T extends {}>(a: T, b: T, keys: (keyof T)[]): boolean => {
  for (const key of keys) {
    if (a[key] !== b[key]) return false;
  }

  return true;
};
```

Again, you can use `ts-transformer-keys` to generate that array for you at compile time.